# Searching for the word "google yahoo" in my database

Tags: php, search

I want to search my database, for example for the word "google yahoo", and when I enter that I should able to look the rows which has google  and yahoo. It is not required to be in the same order and google besides yahoo. No matter wherever it is in the line and give me a simple logic to it. I canto query that thing, something like `select * from table where column like("%google%yahoo%")`. I want to develop this thing in PHP, but how can I insert %. Do I need to use `if` statement so that I can insert % in between the words whenever I find spaces, or is there any other logic to make it simpler?

Comment: This is not a good question for StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check, if a string contains another string, you can use [`stristr`](http://www.php.net/stristr). This could look like the following

```
// for fixed strings
if ( stristr($text, 'google') !== FALSE && stristr($text, 'yahoo') !== FALSE)
    // both found

// for dynamic amount of strings
$searchfor = array('google','yahoo');
foreach ($searchfor as $needle) {
    if (stristr($text, $needle) === FALSE) {
        // $needle not found
    } else {
        // $needle found
    }
}
```

Another possibility to do this would be with [`preg_match`](http://www.php.net/preg_match). You should first be sure, what exactly is it you want to do and then decide which method you want to use.

Comment: Since it is for search engine my search query will be different at all times and also have different number of words(not exactly 2 it can be more than 2) in the query.In that case how i can do it? do i need to take while loop before if condition so that it loops until end of the string

Comment: Please see my edit. But be aware that searching can be very expensive (in terms of execution time). There are various methods to search, if time matters and you are not just playing around, read about those and try to find the one that fits best to your needs

Answer (score 0):

So from what I understand, you want rows where the value of a certain column is either google or yahoo (or whatever words are provided)

### The Query

```
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE columnname LIKE "%google%" AND columnname LIKE "%yahoo%"
```

(replace the `AND` with `OR` if you are ok with either of them)

### The PHP

Essentially your PHP code should [split](http://php.net/manual/en/function.split.php) the given input on the spaces, thus obtaining an array of the words.

Next, when you build the query, for **each** word it should append the following clause:

```
columnname LIKE "%word%"
```

(you may want to filter out common words from your search eg a, in, of, etc)

Comment: Do you mean that do i need to include % front and behind of the word so that %word% can check for anything which has word. I have got this idea i dont no how far it is recommended to do it. Since i only deal with small databases i think it wont be a problem. And other thing is that i want to search for every word(considering each word has index and search independently) whenever user types a sentence or word in the search query.What do u say about this ? which one is better considering the indexes of each word or filtering the each word by adding % to it.

Comment: I am still not very clear about your database, so i can't really say. I assumed you were searching for the words in some text column of a table. But you say words are indexed? Do elaborate.

Comment: for example in my description column i have sentence like this "i am a good boy". Whenever user tries to find this sentence by just typing "am boy". In this case the user should get that sentence which i have written in the quotes. It is something like "%am%boy%" whenever we write this in query. I have seen in some article they have written search with indexes. Here indexes are nothing but the words in arrays.(for example: i[0]="am" i[1]="boy") in this case i can search the result for every word which acts like OR logic.